# Is there a gender-neutral term for 'Godly'?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral

The term ***godly*** is used numerous times in gaming. However, *god* refers to male supernatural beings. God*dess* refers to a female supernatural being, AKA a female god. So, is there a gender-neutral term for ***godly***?

Perhaps some word could refer to a gender-neutral term for godly, such as god*dess*ly? Or perhaps, god-like? This term must be one word.

This term must be usable in male and female contexts.

Sample sentence:

> Hera and Zeus are the [...] beings.

Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54533/discussion-on-question-by-emereal-is-there-a-gender-neutral-term-for-godly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Divine**
>   of, from, or like God or a god.
>   <sub>-[The Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/divine)</sub>

Comment: @Tonepoet Ah, thanks. Usually I use Dictionary.com, is that alright?

Comment: [Dictionary.com and The Free Dictionary by Farlex are fine websites to link, but when you use them, you should pay attention to who is attributed underneath each of the listed entries you use and attribute that source, rather than the name of the website.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/is-tfd-a-rtfm-online-source/6743#6743)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, referencing "the divine" is probably the best alternative since you're wanting an adverb. You could also use "transcendent" or take the prepositional phrase "of the deity" as substitutes to a higher being without any ties to a given sex.

Also, I'm of the mindset of separating the words "sex" and "gender". I understand their interchangeability from a cultural perspective and in normal conversation; however, organisms have sexes but nouns have genders. Yes, they can be used interchangeably, but I had an English teacher explain the formality of it once.